# Show that the two notions of isometry between Riemannian manifold are equivalent

Tags: riemannian-geometry

> We now have two kinds of “metrics” on a Riemannian manifold—the Riemannian metric and the distance function. Correspondingly, there are two definitions of “isometry” between Riemannian manifolds—a Riemannian isometry is a diffeomorphism that pulls one Riemannian metric back to the other, and a metric isometry is a homeomorphism that pulls one distance function back to the other.
>   I am trying to prove that both are equivalent.

The implication ($\Rightarrow$) is quite straightforward. I mean, given a metric isometry on the first sense, there are a isometry on the distance sense.

I am having a lot of problems about how to start the converse.

I understand that I have to show that since there exist an homeomorphism between $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ two riemannian manifolds such that $f^{\ast}d_{h} = d_g$ then necessarily $f^{\ast}h = g.$

This exercise comes from Lee's book of Riemannian geoemtry, and is given the following hint:

> Use the exponential map to show that this homeomorphism is a diffeomorphism.

In fact I don't know how to use this hint to start the exercise.

I do appreciate any hints.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Steenrod_theorem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the author: I realized that hint was a little too cryptic. In the [corrections to the book](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/riemannian.html) (which you should probably download and keep handy), there's a more detailed hint.